# Reduce line height in menu item

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, hyperlink, styles

I have trouble setting the proper line height for one of the menu items on my Wordpress website. [image: Here's how it looks now]

I want the space between two lines to be smaller. Here's a website: [kristinaartgallery.ru](http://kristinaartgallery.ru)

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: share you code or give us the link or a fiddle.

Comment: Please give link, so that we can check

Comment: Sorry! Here's a link to the website: kristinaartgallery.ru

Comment: Problem solved, thanks everybody for checking out my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by adding this in your css file

```
ul.sub-menu .menu-item {
    line-height: 135%;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

If you wanna do that only for that specific sub-menu, add this instead:

```
li#menu-item-271 {
    line-height: 135%;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

next time don't forget to post the related URL, i only got the url by previous questions you made before ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped. Stupid me for forgetting to include the URL...:)

Comment: instead of posting the URL try to put relevant code.